# Can't access json context property in WSO2 ESB after setting in java mediator?

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a WSO2 xml file that calls a ResponseMediator file that contains the following mediator function:

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {
        final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        final String name = "tom";
        json.addProperty("id", 0);
        json.addProperty("name", "tom");
        json.addProperty("age", 32);
        messageContext.setProperty("ID", json.get("id").getAsInt());
        messageContext.setProperty("RESPONSE_BODY", json);
        System.out.println("TESTING JSON : " + messageContext.getProperty("RESPONSE_BODY"));
        return true;
    }
```

I print after setting the json property to make sure the property has been set correctly, which it has. I also added the id separately as a property to make sure it wasn't only happening for json objects.

Then after returning back to WSO2 ESB, I try to log the values and the id comes through, but the json does not.

```
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:RESPONSE_BODY" name="LOGGING JSON PROPERTY"/>
    </log>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:ID" name="LOGGING ID PROPERTY"/>
    </log>
```

```
[2020-12-09 10:35:23,434] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator LOGGING JSON PROPERTY = 
[2020-12-09 10:35:23,434] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator LOGGING ID PROPERTY = 0
```

My question is, since the property is being set correctly in the mediator, what is the correct way to access it in WSO2? I've really only ever worked with passing single values so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Can you try storing the json object as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like setting the property to a String using .toString() like so worked:

```
messageContext.setProperty("RESPONSE_BODY", json.toString());
```